# How to get text next a input tag using document.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML, I need to get the text just after the tag input.
Please note the text `Some text` is not wrapped in any tag.

Do you know a way to get it?

```
<input type="checkbox" /> Some text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, per se.

`querySelector` can only return an element (or `null`), and text is not an element.

You could get the input, and then get the text node next to it.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const text_node = input.nextSibling;
console.log(text_node.data);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" /> Some text
```

NB: Text next to a checkbox *probably* should be expressed using [a label element](https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/).

Comment: I agree that you should probably wrap the text into a tag, if you can modify the HTML. Maybe even give this tag an unique Id. This will make finding the text _much_ more robust. Think what would happen if somebody inserts a hidden element? `<input type="checkbox" /> <div id="someDialogContainer" style="display:none"></div> Some text` - suddenly the text is no longer the `nextSibling`, even though the page looks the same to the user.

Comment: is it possible to do it directly in the querySelector?

Comment: @Radex — I refer you to the first sentence in this answer. No, you can't.